# search data from database asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string db = "Data Source=DESKTOP-R6H3RTP;Initial Catalog=AdmitDB; Integrated Security= true;";
        SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(db);
        mycon.Open();
        String query = "select * from tblPatient where PhoneNo like '"+TextBox1.Text+"%'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, mycon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            lblName.Visible = true;
            lblId.Visible = true;
            lblPNo.Visible = true;
            lblDOB.Visible = true;
            lblName.Text = "PName";
            lblId.Text = "Pid";
            lblPNo.Text = "PhoneNo";
            lblDOB.Text = "PDOB";
        }
        else
        {
            lblNotFound.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

i'm searching from database but just else statement executes don't know why it's not get data from database, if any kind of error then help me please

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't need `if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)`. the cmd executes automatically. you want to check the tables in the dataset.

```
// check the first table for rows.
if(ds.Tables[0].HasRows())
{
    // success. now you can work with the table.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` method returns the number of row that were **modified** by the query. Since `SELECT` query doesn't modify anything in the database - you get `0`.

You should modify your query with a `COUNT(*)` function:
`String query = "select COUNT(*) from tblPatient where PhoneNo like '"+TextBox1.Text+"%'";`

Then you can get that value with `ExecuteScalar()`: 
`if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0)`